# Pearson's Chi-squared statistic

Tags: statistics

Per the example Example: equal frequencies of men and women in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit, what is the exact probability of finding a random sample of size 100 which contains 44 men and 56 women?

I'm trying to understand how does Pearson's Chi-squared statistic know that the correct probability of selecting this sample or more extreme samples is around 0.23?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Exact binomial results.** If $X$ is the number of men in a random sample of size $n$ drawn from a population
with half men and half women, then $X \sim Binom(n, 1/2).$
For $n = 100,$ We have

$$P(X = 44) = {100 \choose 44}(1/2)^{100} = 0.0390$$ to four places.

In R statistical software, this can be computed as follows:

```
 dbinom(44, 100, .5)
 ## 0.03895256
```

The probability of getting 44 or fewer men is 
$P(X \le 44) = 0.1356.$, and by symmetry the probability of
getting 44 or fewer women is also $0.1356.$ Thus the exact probability
of a result 'as or more extreme' than observed is $2(.1356) = .2712$

```
 pbinom(44, 100, .5)
 ## 0.1356265
```

**Approximate result with normal approximation.** Using the normal approximation to the binomial,
$$P(X \le 44) \approx P(Z \le (44 - 50)/5 = -1.2) = .1151$$
because the mean and standard deviation of $X$ are 
$\mu = np = 100(.5) = 50$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{np(1-p} = \sqrt{25} = 5,$ respectively. Here $Z$ is a standard normal random variable.
The probability of a result as or more extreme than observed
is approximated as $2(.1151) =  0.2302.$

```
 pnorm(-1.2)
 ## 0.1150697
```

Note: Using a *continuity correction,* we would have started with $P(X \le 44.5)$ and obtained 0.1357, which is closer to the exact
binomial probability.

**Chi-squared approximation to the GOF statistic.** In much the same way that probabilities involving binomial $X$ can be approximated by normal probabilities, one can show that
probabilities involving the goodness-of-fit (GOF) statistic $Q% can be
approximated by the chi-squared distribution with appropriate
degrees of freedom.

For your example, there are $k = 2$ 'categories', men and women.
The 'expected' numbers of each are $E_1 = E_2 = 50$, the observed numbers
are $X_1 = 44$ and $X_2 = 56,$ respectively. So the GOF statistic is

$$Q = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{(X_i - E_i)^2}{E_i}
= \frac{(44-50)^2}{50} + \frac{(56-50)^2}{50} = 1.44.$$

Because $Q$ is approximately distributed as $Chisq(df = k-1 = 1)$,
we have $P(Q \ge 1.44) = 0.2301.$

```
 X = c(44,56); E = c(50,50)
 sum((X - E)^2/E)
 ## 1.44

 1 - pchisq(1.44, 1)
 ##  0.2301393
```

**Summary** In this simple example, the exact probability of a result
as or more extreme than observed can be found using the binomial
distribution as 0.2712 and the normal
approximation (without continuity correction) is 0.2302. The formulation of the
GOF statistic works for more than $k = 2$ categories and 
it is not convenient to make a useful continuity correction. So the
chi-squared approximation to the GOF statistic gives the approximate
probability 0.23 of getting a result that is as or more extreme.

To show the nature of the approximation of $Chisq(df = 1)$
to the actual distribution of $Q$, we show results from
100,000 simulated experiments drawing 100 people and noting numbers of men and women. The
approximation is generally serviceable when $n$ is large
enough go give all $E_i > 5$ (as here), and it is usually sufficiently accurate in
the right tail (values especially used in testing). But it is
often only a rough approximation for smaller values of $Q$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my question.